# Touch pad click not working on acer laptop

Tags: windows-xp, touchpad

I have two operating systems Windows XP on My Laptop. In one OS cursors move using touchpad but click not working on touchpad.

In the bottom side there is there is button for click and right click.
its working good but touch pad click or selection not working only cursor moves.

What is the problem?

Comment: don't include your email address in the question - no one's going to email you the answer

Comment: Install the drivers for your touchpad. They probably came on a CD or DVD with your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what make of laptop and what utilities are loaded it makes finding the settings more difficult. Try looking in the control panel, if you don't have a setting specifically for the touchpad then it should be included in the mouse settings, you should have a tab that shows the touchpad settings, if it is not there then look for an "advanced" tab.